# WAR File too big

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I have deployed my WAR file to Tomcat, but it's almost 160 MB and server is running really slow. Can any one suggest to me how to speed up things up?

Comment: Do you know why your WAR file is 160 MB? What are you putting in?

Comment: You need to provide more info than that. There is no way to answer your question. Why is the file so big?

Comment: I must tell you guys I am not using eclipse and all.. it's xwiki tool I am working on

Comment: I don't think the size of the war has anything to do with the slowness of the application. Profile your app.

Comment: That's what I'm always talking about: Developers always relying on 3rd Party frameworks. Is it necessary to have 136MB of jars?

Comment: What's the alternative, Buhake Sindi?  Writing all the features you rely on in the frameworks from scratch?  There's a germ of truth in your complaint - choose frameworks judiciously - but I don't think rolling your own is the answer in every case.

Comment: Looks like a first question from a first timer.  I think your frustration threshold is set too low.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is that necessarily a problem?  If you have a lot of 3rd party JARs your WAR file might be that large.  What can you remove and still have the app run?

If we assume that size is not necessarily the reason why your app server is slow, what could be the root cause?

I'd recommend monitoring your app server under some moderate load using Visual VM with all the plugins installed.  It'll show you what's happening with heap, CPU, threads, object creation, and lots of other interesting things.

I'd also turn on Chrome tools and see what's happening when pages are loaded and rendered.

Have you run YSlow! to see how your pages perform?

You don't have root cause for slow.  I'd find it before I guessed.

Update - Just a point of reference: I have a web app that uses Spring 3, all its dependencies, and several other 3rd party JARs.  The WAR file is 31MB.  You *might* have a problem.